# Pointer calculation in Linux Kernel allocation implementation

Tags: c, linux, pointers, caching

From the guide [Understanding The Linux Kernel, 3rd Edition](http://www.johnchukwuma.com/training/UnderstandingTheLinuxKernel3rdEdition.pdf) , chapter *8.2.12. Allocating a Slab Object* , there is the following piece of code:

```
void * kmem_cache_alloc(kmem_cache_t *cachep, int flags)
{  
    unsigned long save_flags;  
    void *objp;  
    struct array_cache *ac;  
    local_irq_save(save_flags);  
    ac = cache_p->array[smp_processor_id()];  
    if (ac->avail) 
    {  
       ac->touched = 1;
       objp = ((void**)(ac+1))[--ac->avail];  
    } else  
        objp = cache_alloc_refill(cachep, flags);  
    local_irq_restore(save_flags);  return objp; 
}
```

Now, look at the line `((void**)(ac+1))[--ac->avail]`, according to the guide:

> Because the local cache array is stored right after the ac descriptor,
>   ((void**)(ac+1))[--ac->avail] gets the address of that free object and
>   decreases the value of ac->avail.

But, since `ac` is a pointer to type `struct array_cache` which contains the following fields (in this order)-

> [type] unsigned int
>
> [name] avail
>
> [description] Number of pointers to available objects in the local cache.
>    The field also acts as the index of the first free slot in the cache.
>
> [type] unsigned int
>
> [name] limit
>
> [description] Size of the local cache that is, the maximum number of pointers in the local cache.
>
> [type] unsigned int
>
> [name] batch_count
>
> [description] Chunk size for local cache refill or emptying.
>
> [type] unsigned int
>
> [name] touched
>
> [description] Flag set to 1 if the local cache has been recently used.

so `ac+1` will point to to the second byte of `avail` value (or 3rd byte in opposite Endian case) which makes no sense at all.

Am I getting this the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're mistaken.

Pointer arithmetic is in terms of the type being pointed at, not bytes.

Consider this:

```
int a[2], *p = a;

++p;
```

This leaves `p` equal to `&a[1]`, not `((char *) &a[0]) + 1`. So that increment will increment the actual pointer value by `sizeof *p`, i.e. `sizeof (int)`.

Remember that array indexing works through pointer arithmetic, so it has to be this way for that reason too.

It's quite common when implementing various data structures in C that you have a block of memory that starts with an instance of some `struct`, and then comes other data (often described by field in the `struct`). The first byte of that data is then at `sp + 1`, assuming `sp` is a pointer to the `struct`, just as the code you showed.

Comment: Can you please provide more common usages and examples of this type of coding? i would have expected the use of another struct that wraps this data, and this wrapper struct would have a field of a pointer to the other struct, and another field that points to the other data. This way is clean and clear. Why use such code? what is it good for?